# How to retrieve alphanumeric rows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table as follow:

```
|  Id  |FirstName|LastName|IdentityNumber|
   1        A         B       A2301c12
   2        C         D       12345
   3        E         F       ABcD1
   4        G         H       AAA7622II
```

And then i want get only records that their column values is alphanumeric (contain alphabetic and numeric) via linq-to-entities.

Desired output:

```
|  Id  |FirstName|LastName|IdentityNumber|
   1        A         B       A2301c12
   3        E         F       ABcD1
   4        G         H       AAA7622II
```

**Note:** Iam using Entity Framwork 6 and devart provider for oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
var res = dataSource
    .MyTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(s => s.IdentityNumber.Any(Char.IsDigit) && s.IdentityNumber.Any(Char.IsLetter));
```

Comment: @Amir This code moves your data to memory to apply the `Char.IsDigit` and `Char.IsLetter` functions. I am not sure if any data provider is capable of converting this to proper SQL (although you could try it by removing `AsEnumerable()` in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

This query assumes retrieving all the data from the table (it might be a huge amount of data) and only then the data is sorted on the client :

```
var res = dataSource
 .MyTable
 .AsEnumerable()
 .Where(s => s.IdentityNumber.Any(Char.IsDigit) && s.IdentityNumber.Any(Char.IsLetter));
```

We recommend you using this code:

```
var results = dbcontext.TESTALPHANUMs.Where(p => OracleFunctions.RegexpLike(p.IDENTITYNUMBER, "[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*$") && ! OracleFunctions.RegexpLike(p.IDENTITYNUMBER, "^[A-Za-z]*$")).ToList();
```

In this case, only the necessary data will be retrieved from the database.